# Optimal way to do CPU bound task in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have to process a lot of data in my Lambda code and this computation could be parallelized. I am currently using single-threaded Python code and want to optimize it. I thought about converting it to multi-threaded Python code, but anyway it seems that Amazon Lambda doesn't have enough resources. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: "it seems that Amazon Lambda doesn't have enough resources" You should clarify the reason why you think so

Comment: Please provide more specifications!

Answer (score 5):

AWS Lambda now supports up to 10 GB of memory and 6 vCPU cores for Lambda Functions

If you want to do CPU bound, parallelized functions on Lambda, always remember these core behaviour

- The total amount number of vCPU (which correlate to the optimal thread count) is dictated by how much memory you assigned for that Lambda function

> Lambda allocates CPU power in proportion to the amount of memory configured. Memory is the amount of memory available to your Lambda function at runtime. You can increase or decrease the memory and CPU power allocated to your function using the Memory (MB) setting. To configure the memory for your function, set a value between 128 MB and 10,240 MB in 1-MB increments. At 1,769 MB, a function has the equivalent of one vCPU (one vCPU-second of credits per second).

- Lambda is also severely limited by the maximum amount of time it can be run: 900 seconds (15 minutes)

Depend on how your application has been architectured, you can improve the performance with these things in mind

- It does support multi-threaded / multi-core processing. How-to in python can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/parallel-processing-in-python-with-aws-lambda/)
- When you hit the upper limits of a single Lambda run, think about ways to break the work to multiple Lambdas running in parallel if possible. That level of horizontal scaling is what Lambda excels at.